# Can I update Fabric peer container image?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Newer docker container image for fabric-peer is released time to time. If I create a container with fabric-peer v1.03, then can I update the container to v1.04 keeping configuration and ledger in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you upgrade the peer's container from version 1.0.x to v1.0.y such that y > x, that is safe.

I presume that instructions on how to upgrade to v1.1 will be published when v1.1 will be finally released.

As for the configuration and the ledger - since you use docker you can just put the files on a shared volume between the host and the docker.

Comment: Thank you, I understand base is same as other docker container.